# Update to new minecraft launcher

Tags: updates, launcher, minecraft

I have been playing minecraft for a long time on ubuntu but I have always used the old 'java' launcher.
Since there is a new launcher I would like to update minecraft to that. 
I have searched the internet but can't update it whatever I do even reinstalling the game won't fix it.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about new launcher but Minecraft is available as a snap in Ubuntu. It recue users from java-setup hassle. Open Terminal and type- 
sudo snap install mc-installer